# RingCentral Forwarding Number API `ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers` permission

Tags: roles, user-permissions, ringcentral

When I try the RingCentral Get Forwarding Number API:

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/forwarding-number`

I get this error:

```
{
 "errorCode" : "CMN-408",
  "message" : "In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers] permission for requested resource.",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "CMN-408",
    "message" : "In order to call this API endpoint, user needs to have [ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers] permission for requested resource.",
    "permissionName" : "ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers"
  } ],
  "permissionName" : "ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers"
}
```

I don't see this permission in the Online Account Portal (https://service.ringcentral.com), even under the Super Admin role. How can I resolve this and access this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers` is a user permission that is configured in the Online Account Portal. The user's assigned role needs to have the following corresponding permission in the Online Account Portal:

`User Settings` > `Messages & Notifications`

You can see this in the Online Account Portal under:

`Users` > `Roles` > `{Role Name}`

For example:

[image]

You can verify if your user has this permission by calling the following endpoint:

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/authz-profile`

This will return a JSON object with a `permissions` property with an array of permissions. This permission looks like the following:

```
{
    "permission": {
        "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/permission/ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers",
        "id": "ReadUserForwardingFlipNumbers",
        "assignable": false,
        "readOnly": false,
        "siteCompatible": "Independent"
    },
    "effectiveRole": {
        "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/user-role/3",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "scopes": [
        "Self"
    ]
},
```